# Cycle between the last two windows (similar to CMD+TAB)

Tags: macos, applications

I generally have two screens but I'm stuck with just a laptop for a while.

Is there a way to cycle between the last two apps you're using? <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> would cycle between all open apps. I'd like just between the last two.

A workaround I have is to maximize the screen of the two applications I'm using, and <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd><kbd>←</kbd> to cycle between the Desktops but is there something easier that happens in the same Desktop?

Comment: Cmd/Tab already does that, so long as you let go in between & let the 2nd app come to the front. That then makes your previous 1st app the 2nd - therefore 1st to switch to when you Cmd/Tab.

Comment: Cool. Let me drop it into a quick answer, for sake of completeness ;)

Comment: Please accept Tetsujin's answer as solving your issue, thx!

Comment: Done, thank you again. Quite embarrassing I didn't see the answer myself but .. yeah :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>    already does that, so long as you let go in between & let the 2nd app come to the front.

That then makes your previous 1st app the 2nd - therefore 1st to switch to when you  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   <kbd>Tab ⇥</kbd>